# Why increment_id changed when update order status using rest api?

Tags: php, magento2

I want to update order status to complete using webapi

here is my testing code :

```
$data = array (
        'entity' =>
        array (
            'entity_id' => $id,
            'status' => 'complete',
        ),
    );

    $this->generateApiToken();

    $ch = curl_init("https://$this->link/rest/V1/orders/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Content-Type: application/json",
                                                "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($this->token) ));

    $cusJsonData = curl_exec($ch);
```

and when this code runs, the status updated correctly , but the increment_id changed.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your next experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please also post the script as text and not as a picture

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this on v2.2.5, and put it down to a bug in Magento's API.

To get round this, you need to specify the original `increment_id` along with the `entity_id` when doing status updates.

Your JSON should look similar to this:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "entity_id":23,
    "increment_id":"0000000153",
    "state":"processing",
    "status":"processing"
  }
}
```

Also, not sure why `state` and `status` is required, I just chalk this up to Magento's awful API.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL for Magento 2 API. I guess there is no such specific API to update order status to complete.

URL: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/

Go to salesOrderRepositoryV1 or salesOrderManagementV1.

Comment: The swagger documentation is awful - In no way does the Magento documentation state required fields, nor acceptable values for such fields.